# Core Data and objects queues: Reduce memory usage

Tags: objective-c, core-data, memory-management

I need to implement persistence of an objects queue using Core Data. The only operations are peek, delete and pop. Can someone suggest what is the best way to do this from the performance and memory usage point of view? There could be thousands of objects and I don't want to keep them all in memory.

```
[[DataManager shared] push: myItem1];
[[DataManager shared] push: myItem2];
.....
[[DataManager shared] push: myItem10000];
.....


MyItem* item = [[DataManager shared] peek];
while(item != nil){
   if([self processItem: item]){
      [[DataManager shared] delete: item];
   }else{
      break;
   }
   item = [[DataManager shared] peek];
}
```

Thanks in advance. Sorry if this is a silly question I'm new to Core Data and as far as I understood it's different from sqllite data store and I cannot use sql techniques in Core Data.

Comment: What about Core Data? What's your final goal?

Comment: The goal is to make high performance objects queue data store with low memory usage. Core Data saves objects in memory which means that if I push 1000 objects they will be in memory. Is there any way to release memory when objects are flushed to store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Core Data saves objects in memory which means that if I push 1000
>   objects they will be in memory.

Based on your comment you can avoid this choosing the right saving factor. I'll try to explain.
Suppose you have 1000 objects to save. You can decide a *save frequency* (say 100) followed by a `reset` call to remove the object graph for a specific context.

In addition, If you have many objects into memory but you need to reduce the memory footprint you can call `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` with `NO` parameter to turn an object into fault. Faulting an object means clearing its in-memory property values.

Hope it helps.

P.S. I really suggest to take a look to [High Performance Core Data](http://highperformancecoredata.com).

Comment: Also avoid the XML store-- the whole thing's in memory regardless of refreshObject faulting.  [This is also a great link,](http://finalize.com/2013/01/04/core-data-issues-with-memory-allocation/) as I've been not seeing much shrinkage of the MOC... may have to try the sledgehammer approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. Excellent links. In my case reset call did the job but I had to put the queue entities to a separate context.